# How can I use sed to change my target dir in this shell command line?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I use this command line to find all the SVGs (thousands) in a directory and convert them to PNGs using Inkscape.  Works great.  Here is my issue.  It outputs the PNGs in the same directory.  I would like to change the target directory.

```
for i in `find /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR -name "*.svg"`; do inkscape $i --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png=`echo $i | sed -e 's/svg$/png/'` -w 700 ; done
```

It appears $i is the file_path + file_name, and sed does a search/replace on the file extension.  How do I search/replace my file_path?  Or is there a better way to define a different target path within this command line?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: add another `s///` in `sed` to do that search/replace, or use something like `basename` or bash's `${x##y}`/`${x%%y}` to do the filename generation instead

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
destdir="DIR"   # replace with your desired directory name
mkdir -p "$destdir"
find /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR -name "*.svg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" i; do
    destfile="$destdir/$(basename -s .svg "$i").png"
    inkscape "$i" --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png="$destfile" -w 700
done
```

or

```
destdir="DIR"
mkdir -p "$destdir"
for i in /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR/*.svg; do
    destfile="$destdir/$(basename -s .svg "$i").png"
    inkscape "$i" --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png="$destfile" -w 700
done
```

This may be off-topic but it is not recommended to use a `for` loop relying on the  word-splitting especially when dealing with the filenames. Please consider the filenames and the pathnames may contain whitespace, newline, tab or other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Or with a one-liners (split for readability)

```
find /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR -name "*.svg" |
   xargs -I{} sh -c 'inkscape "{}" --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png='$destdir'/$(basename {} .svg).png -w 700'
```

Might work with find built-in exec:

```
find /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR -name "*.svg" -exec sh -c 'inkscape "{}" --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png='$destdir'/$(basename {} .svg).png -w 700' \;
```

Or by passing target-dir as arguments, to simplify quoting.

```
find /home/wyatt/test/svgsDIR -name "*.svg" -exec sh -c 'inkscape "$1" --export-background-opacity=0 --export-png="$2/$(basename $1 .svg).png" -w 700' '{}' "$targetdir"  \;
```